# civiReport with financial type and line item financial types

Tags: civireport, financial-types

Is there a report that displays both the overarching financial type and the individual line item financial types for contributions?

civiCRM Contribution and paid event pages require a financial type to be set. We often use complex pricing options with price sets with multiple financial types.

I am looking for a report or search that shows both the overarching financial type (from the page) and the individual line items (from the price set). Find Contributions and Contribution Detail report only display the overarching financial type. Bookkeeping transaction report displays only the line item.

Does a report/search exist that displays both?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no such report provided by CiviCRM by default. But there is an extension called '[Extended Report](https://civicrm.org/extensions/extended-reports)' which provides report with additional columns and filters.

The report 'Extended Report - Contributions with Price Set data' or 'Extended Report - Price Set Line Items' from the extension may be the one you looking for.

Cheers

Pradeep

Comment: thanks so much, I will take a look

Comment: Let us know if it worked for you.

Comment: it did! thanks so much!